# Azure Function never executes using Mongoose + CosmosDB

Tags: node.js, azure, mongoose, azure-functions

I've made an azure function using mongoose. I added the cosmosdb env variables inside the local.settings.json. I did npm init in the folder and installed the following package.

```
{
  "name": "signup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.9.1"
  }
}
```

When I run it in the cloud, it hangs for about a minute, then returns nothing. No status code. No `console.log(err)`. If I run the azure function locally, then it only outputs:

request body I'm using

```
{"email": "bobjones@gmail.com", "password": "Password4$", "username" : "bobjones", "over21": true, "role": "Buyer", "phoneNumber": "7383223333", "fullname": null, "address1": null, "address2": null, "city": null, "state": null, "zip": null, "passwordCreated": null}
```

```
LETS SIGNUP
Connection to CosmosDB successful
```

If I deploy it to the cloud to test from there, then when I run it, it'll complete, but nothing outputs. No status code. 
So it doesn't appear to make it inside the router.post since console.log("inside POST") never outputted. I'm starting to suspect it's a mongoose compatibility issue, but I'm not sure. Does mongoose have limitations with azure functions? I've only seen one article on google talking about mongoose and azure functions so I think it's supported, but not much documentation talking about it. I appreciate any help!

```
const express = require("express");
const User = require("./models/user");
const mongoose = require("azure-functions-mongooser");
const mongoose1 = require("mongoose");

const router = express.Router();


module.exports = async function (context, req) {


    mongoose1
        .connect(
            "mongodb://" +
            process.env.COSMOSDB_HOST +
            ":" +
            process.env.COSMOSDB_PORT +
            "/" +
            process.env.COSMOSDB_DBNAME +
            "?ssl=true&replicaSet=globaldb",
            {
                auth: {
                    user: process.env.COSMODDB_USER,
                    password: process.env.COSMOSDB_PASSWORD
                }
            }
        )
        .then(() => console.log("Connection to CosmosDB successful"))
        .catch(err => console.error(err));

            console.log("INSIDE POST")

    router.post("/api/signup", (req, res, next) => {
        console.log("SIGNUP BACKEND");

            const user = new User({
                email: req.body.email,
                password: req.body.password,
                username: req.body.username,
                over21: req.body.over21,
                role: req.body.role,
                phoneNumber: req.body.phoneNumber,
                fullName: req.body.fullName,
                address1: req.body.address1,
                address2: req.body.address2,
                city: req.body.city,
                state: req.body.state,
                zip: req.body.zip,
                passwordCreated: Date.now()
            });
            user
                .save()
                .then(result => {
                    console.log("MADE IT");

                    console.log(result);
                    res.status(201).json({
                        message: "User created!",
                        result: result
                    });
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    let error = err.message;
                    console.log(err);
                     if (error.includes("Error, expected `phoneNumber` to be unique.")) {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error: "Phone number has already been used"
                        });
                    } else if (error.includes("Error, expected `email` to be unique.")) {
                        res.status(500).json({
                            error: "Email has already been used"
                        });
                    }
                });
        });

};
```

User model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
//const uniqueValidator = require("mongoose-unique-validator");

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
  username: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  over21: { type: String, required: true },
  role: { type: String, required: true },
  fullName: { type: String },
  address1: { type: String },
  phoneNumber: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
  address2: { type: String },
  city: { type: String },
  state: { type: String },
  zip: { type: String },
  passwordCreated: { type: Date },

});


module.exports = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not an issue with mongoose but how you are handling promises in your code. Since your exported function is defined as `async` all your promises should be awaited using the `await` keyword otherwise your function will exit before your code completes execution, which is why you don't see any logs in the console.
On the other hand as is the code won't return the response you expect because it not returning properly.

You can check the [Azure Functions Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node#exporting-a-function) for more information:

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I've been playing with trying to get it working, but it'll just timeout. I'm very new to async/await. I've only had experience writing promises with ```.then``` I made an example azure function that should get any auction that has a date greater than today. I tried to write in the async format, but it just hangs. Also my callback as you mentioned is using the way the documentation describes now. I'm not really sure how what the issue is. Can you provide an example with your answer?  https://pastebin.com/bBnsJ9vJ

Comment: The awaiting seem to be ok now, but I believe your have still have an issue on how you are returning from the function. A plain return with an object should provide you with the desired results as long as your `function.json` has the following bindings configured:
  {
    "type": "http",
    "direction": "out",
    "name": "$return"
  }